# How to add custom fonts in React Native Version 0.69

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

### Problem

I am trying to load custom fonts in my *React Native* App. However, I am using version 0.69 and I don't know how to add them anymore, [because](https://reactnative.dev/blog/2022/06/21/version-069):

> - link and unlink commands have been removed in the favour of autolinking
> - Removed assets and hooks from react-native.config.js – you'll need to remove these properties from your config

So how can this now be done in *Android* and *iOS* now?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [react-native-asset](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-asset) for `0.69` using these command:

```
  npx react-native-asset
```

Comment: They also use the deprecated `assets` property

Comment: yeah but It works correctly and it will always work so no worries using it.